# Java: String containing 2 decimal to int/double/anything

Tags: java

Silly question but couldn't find the right answer on Google (or didn't know what to search :)

I have a string containing this number: 3.0.1
How can I convert it to an Int/double/float/whatever in order to check if it's bigger/smaller/equal to...

I don't mind cutting it to get only the first number (3).

Thanks in advance,
Lior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String a = "3.0.1";
int b = Integer.parseInt(a.substring(0,1)); // will give you 3.
```

Comment: `parseInt(..)` could throw an exception

Comment: @Hunter McMillen -- so could yourString.charAt() :-) .. I'm leaving the runtime exception catching to the OP.

Answer (score 3):

If you'd like to have the whole string evaluated...

```
String s = "3.0.1";
String arr[] = s.split("\\.");

int value = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]) * 100 + 
            Integer.parseInt(arr[1]) * 10 + 
            Integer.parseInt(arr[2]);
```

Add try catch blocks as you see fit.

Comment: Be more specific and I can help you. I don't have access to a Java IDE at the moment. I assume the problem is my syntax somewhere, I've been in Actionscript (Flex) too long this summer.

Comment: Array index Out of bounds exception

Comment: That's very strange. If you're feeding it a String that has less to it than "x.y.z" that would happen. If you need a solution that is more extendable (1 number to n numbers) it would be a little more verbose but not too difficult.

Comment: Basically, as I mentioned in the OP, I'm fine with just finding the first number. But thank you for your solution, pointed me to the right direction. Will look into it!

Comment: The reason the exception is showing up is because the `split` method wants a *regular expression* - the `.` is a special character.  Try `String arr[] = s.split("\\.");` instead.  Otherwise, I think this is probably closer to the method I would prefer.

Comment: Thanks, @X-Zero. Not being able to test my own answer is a pain, but wanted to provide the OP with a different option. Appreciate the correction.

Comment: Hey, I would have expected you original answer to work too - I had to look up the documentation to figure out why `arr` was empty.

Answer (score 1):

```
String yourString = "3.0.1";
String firstDigit = Character.toString(yourString.charAt(0));
int first = 0;

try
{
    first = Integer.parseInt(firstDigit);
}
catch(NumberFormatException nfe)
{
    System.err.println(nfe.getMessage());
}
```